# python book searching algorithm

Tags: python, search

I'm having a error in python search query:

```
return eval(raw_input(prompt))File "<string>", line 1 Bel and the Dragon
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

here is my code:

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error 

def searchBook():
    search = input('Search Book?')
    search = '%' + search + '%'

    try:
        conn = MySQLConnection(host='localhost',
                           database='python_mysql',
                           user='root',
                           password='')

        query = 'SELECT * FROM books where title LIKE %s'
        data = (search, search)

        cursor = conn.cursor()      
        cursor.execute(query, data)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        print(row)

    except Error as error:
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    searchBook()
```

Comment: what is `eval(raw_input(prompt))` doing?

Comment: that is an error master

Comment: can you add the code where you use `return eval(raw_input(prompt))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking it down a bit,

```
s = raw_input(prompt)      # prompt user to enter a string
res = eval(s)              # try to evaluate the string as a Python expression ?!
```

so if the user entered `4 + 6`, `eval` would run it and return `10`.

`Bel and the Dragon` is not a Python expression, *therefore* trying to `eval` it gives a syntax error.